# Unable to generate .aab file in react native. Expo error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

i am unable to generate an .aab file for android release. Our Releases are stuck since 2 days. Looked at multiple answers here and there, but nothing worked. Will appreciate any possible solutions.

What i am doing? Running **./gradlew bundleProductionRelease** from the android folder in the react native project.

What i am expecting? That this should create a **bundle(.aab)** file for the app.

Getting below expo related errors.

[image]

Below are my react native and expo library versions in the project.

```
"expo": "44.0.6",

"expo-application": "4.0.2",

"expo-updates": "0.11.6",

"react-native": "0.66.4",
```

Thanks in advance, and can share other details if necessary for getting to root cause.

Comment: Same error is mentioned here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19259

Comment: hello @robertklep thanks for pointing out, seems that is for different react native version than mine, but will get back after trying some solutions mentioned there.

Comment: what worked for me as of now is increasing the react-native version to 0.66.5 and increasing expo-updates to 0.11.7